# TCP sockets transfer from windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

i am doing a sample in which I am trying to transfer data from client(windows phone 8) app to  windows form app(which acts as a server) using TCP.

In windows form app I am creating a listener like this

```
         TcpListener tcpListener = null;

        IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0];
        try
        {
            // Set the listener on the local IP address
            // and specifing the port.
            tcpListener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, 13);
            tcpListener.Start();
            output = "Waiting for a connection...";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            output = "Error: " + e.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(output);
        }

        while (true)
        {

            Thread.Sleep(10);
             TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

            byte[] bytes = new byte[256];

            NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
          }
```

In windows phone 8 app i am using managed sockets to connect to the listener some thing like this

```
    public Task SendUsingManagedSocketsAsync(string strServerIP)
    {


        // enable asynchronous task completion
        completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        // create a new socket 
        var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream,
            ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // create endpoint 
        var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(strServerIP);
        var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, PORT);

        // create event args 
        var args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        args.RemoteEndPoint = endpoint;
        args.Completed += SocketConnectCompleted;

        // check if the completed event will be raised. If not, invoke the handler manually. 
        if (!socket.ConnectAsync(args))
            SocketConnectCompleted(args.ConnectSocket, args);

        return completionSource.Task;
    }
```

But i got an socket error of connection refused. Is my approach is correct, how to connect a tcp listener through windows phone.. Here i cannot change the code of windows form app as it was my server code in the real time.. Or is it compulsary to change the code of my server....